# Matching/comparing two text strings and returning a result

Tags: javascript

I got an input field were a user can type keywords for example "jeans". When "jeans" have been typed into the input field a list of search suggestions comes up which contains the word or part of the word "jeans".

I would like to match the string typed in the input field with the text that is shown in the search suggestions, and make the text from the search suggestions which matches the text typed in the input field bold. So far I can return a text string of what is typed in the input field, and I can also return a text string of what the search suggestions contains. Now I would need to compare thoes two, and my best guess is to use match().

However i keep getting null as a result in my function below. I need to use plain Vanilla JS for the solution.

```
    //get the text from the search suggestions list as a string
    var searchSuggestList = document.getElementsByClassName('search-suggest__list')[0];
    var searchSuggestListText = searchSuggestList.innerText;

    //get value from input field as a string
    var searchSuggestInput = document.getElementsByClassName('js-search-suggest-input')[0].value

    var result = searchSuggestInput.match(searchSuggestListText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looking for the value of `searchSuggestInput` in `searchSuggestListText`, you need to invert your variables:

```
var result = searchSuggestListText.match(searchSuggestInput);
```

Keep in mind that `searchSuggestInput` will be treated as a regular expression. It's probably a good idea to read through the [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) documentation before continuing with this approach, especially the section that describes how the method will return different results depending on the presence of the `/g` flag.

Comment: Hmm... inverting the variables as you say still gives me a null :/

Comment: `console.log("blue jeans\nwhite jeans\nwhatever".match("jeans"))`

Comment: Actually it works, but apparently it is case sensitive. so when I search for "JEANS" in uppercase it retuns me some result.

Comment: You can make it case-insensitive by providing an `/i` flag to the regular expression. Also, don't forget to [escape the input text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) to be suitable for use in regular expressions.